# Android put 2 textview in same order

Tags: android, textview

I got 2 textviews.

1st

```
   <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="If you would like to provide feedback on the ehospice app, or report an error or problem, please "
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

2nd (in my activity i use clicklistener on it and underline it)

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/send_us_an_email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="send us an email."
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

When i launch app 2nd TextView goes in a new line how is possible to make in final like this:

```
If you would like to provide feedback on the ehospice app, or report an error or problem, please send us an email. (send us an email. is underlined didnt know to to put here :))
```

Comment: use these textview in relative layout put 2nd textview on right side of 1st textview

Comment: if i put it in a relative layout it wont be a single text . On large screens it would look ok , but on small screens will be like 2 rows 1st textview and 2nd textview will stay away

Comment: of course due to small screen it will be two rows.. so just put these textviews in scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should it in one TextView, then you should use something like this:

```
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("If you would like to provide feedback on the ehospice app, or report an error or problem, please send us an email.");
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                //your code for click
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, position_of_first_send_email_character, ss.length() - 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
        textView.setText(ss);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Because the way with horizontal orientation wouldn't work with this large first string in small devices

Comment: here i do clicklistener on 1 text but i need only on send us an email.

Comment: this onClick will trigger only if you click at "send email" text if done everything as i post here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a liner layout set `orientation` property to `horizontal`with these two as child views of the linear layout..